# Condition(s) that satisfy this equality

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having difficulty understanding how my book came up with this answer.

> Define $a \star b =ab+2b$, and suppose $x \star y = y \star x$. Then which of the following must be true?
>
> A. $x+y=1$.
>
> B. $y=0$.
>
> C. $x=y$.
>
> D. $x=-2$.
>
> E. $xy=0$.

How did the text conclude that $x=y$ or C is the answer ?

Comment: What does $x \star y$ mean in this context?

Comment: What *are* x,y, anyway? Real numbers?

Comment: If $\star$ can be *any* operation, then the only condition that guarantees $x\star y = y\star x$ is $x=y$. But the question is not which condition guarantees the conclusion $x\star y = y\star x$, but rather, which condition is a *necessary conclusion*. Unless $\star$ is specified, **nothing** is a necessary conclusion of the condition. Are you *sure* they don't specify what $\star$ is, or give conditions that are satisfied by it?

Comment: There are lots of possible answers depending on what it means. If we don't know which it is, I don't think we can be any help. Surely the text you found it from must explain somewhere?!

Comment: Sorry Let me re-edit my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** So you are told that $xy+2y=yx+2x$. Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

We need the context to know what operation means $\star$, but i guess the equality $x=y$ must be true only if the operation $\star$ is a kind of operation such like division for example, that doesn't satisfy the conmutative property, and only in case that $x=y$ the equality $x \star y = y \star x$  is satisfied.

Sorry about my English, I hope you can understand me :D

Comment: I think you will have to edit your answer to reflect the edited version of the OP's question.